# How should different RDBMS dependencies be handled in Gemfile with bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I have a project that can be deployed on either MySQL or Oracle.

What strategy should I use to make the Gemfile require the correct library (mysql2 or ruby-oci8) when specified in the database.yml (or elsewhere)?

Specifically, I am trying to avoid requiring both in the Gemfile as the installation of ruby-oci8 is problematic depending on your platform.  I'm also hoping that the standard "bundle install" can be issued rather than requiring additional flags depending on your database selection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there is no standard way of defining optional dependencies.

what you can do is put the dependencies into different groups:

```
group :mysql do
  ...
end

group :oracle do
  ...
end
```

but then you need to use the --without flag in order to install the one or the other.