# How to make gemfile database agnostic and also check in gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've seen suggestions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932195/how-should-different-rdbms-dependencies-be-handled-in-gemfile-with-bundler) that say you can make your open source rails app database agnostic by putting groups in your gemfile and specifying --without when running bundle install.

However, that would not keep the original database out of gemfile.lock, which you are supposed to check in to your repo, so wouldn't it still be a problem for anyone who used a different database?

Is there any way to not specify the database in gemfile.lock?

Comment: Looking (for example) at devise it seems they use sqlite in the [gemfile.lock](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/Gemfile.lock), yet it's database agnostic when installed... :s

Comment: interesting. I didn't realize that. I am using devise and don't see sqllite in my gemfile or gemile.lock anywhere. They have it in their gemfile.lock too.